# How to remove junk symbol in string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string variable with content as follows:

```
str =  "abc�"
```

How to check and remove whether string have this "�" symbol or not in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: don't know about ruby, can you try replace all `'[^\x00-\x7F]'` by empty? does it achieve your goal?

Comment: @apneadiving no even God doesn't know, that's why he asked here. :-)

Comment: What's the source of the junk? Is it always the same character or is this one of a class of characters?

Comment: Are you sure, that this is really THE symbol "�", and not just a placeholder for a symbol which can not be displayed by your browser or console (whatever you use to look at the output)?

Answer (score 2):

The character “�” is [`U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character). If your string literally contains that character, then removing it is as simple as:

```
cleaned_string = str.gsub "�", ''
```

or (assuming you want to avoid typing a literal “�” in your code):

```
cleaned_string = str.gsub "\ufffd", ''
```

Wikipedia says this about this character:

> It is used to indicate problems when a system is not able to render a stream of data to a correct symbol.

So it likely that your real problem is that you are not correctly handling the source of this string — most likely this is an encoding problem. For example if the string was originally `abcé`, but in ISO-8859-1 encoding, but some system interpreted it as UTF-8, then the final character, `é`, would be invalid, and that system may then display it as “�”, which is what your program is seeing. (The Wikipedia page has another example.)

If this is an encoding issue, then depending on where this data is coming from it may be too late for you to do anything, the real data may already be lost and the best you can do is to strip out these characters (or you may prefer to leave them to indicate where there is an problem). Otherwise you need to be careful when reading data into your program that you read it as the appropriate encoding so that this data isn’t lost.

If character encodings are completly new to you then a good place to start learning about them is Joel Spolsky’s article [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

(1) What do you get, when you have

str.inspect

displayed?

(2) If you know, what range of characters is allowed in your string, you could go the other way round and replace any character which is not in this range.